# C++ class design: Covariance

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, class-design, covariant

## The Problem

I want to implement a number of algorithms that work on a graph and return scores for node-pairs indicating whether those nodes are similar. The algorithms should work on a single node-pair and on all possible node-pairs. In the latter case a collection/matrix should be returned.

## My Approach

The algorithms derive from

```
class SimilarityAlgorithm {
public:
  Base(const Graph& G);

  virtual double run(node u, node v) = 0; // indices for nodes in the graph

  virtual ScoreCollection& runAll() = 0;
}
```

Now the algorithms differ in memory usage. Some algorithms might be symmetric and the scores for (u, v) and (v, u) are identical. This requires different ScoreCollection-types that should be returned. An example would be a sparse-matrix and a triangular matrix that both derive from `ScoreCollection`.

This would boil down to covariant return types:

```
class SpecificAlgorithm : SimilarityAlgorithm {
public:
  double run(node u, node v);

  // The specific algorithm is symmetric and thus uses a symmetric matrix to save memory
  SymmetricScoreCollection& runAll();
}
```

## Question

- Is this design approach a good idea for this problem?
- Should the fact that the collections are all implemented as matrices be exposed?

Comment: Are you sure you want to take the nodes by value? And the try at covariance should work.

Comment: The nodes are actually just typedefs for unsigned long. I think in this case by value is fine.

Comment: Sure, if that's the case, identity is probably unimportant.

Comment: You can make 'SimilarityAlgorithm' a class template and pass in the needed return type for 'runAll()' if the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design seems appropriate for the problem you describe.

**Problem:**

However, there is a problem with your `SpecificAlgorithm` :  `runAll()` doesn't return the same type as the virtual function of the base class. So it won't be called (or more probably, your code won't compile because of a missing virtual function).

**Solution:**

Use also a polymorphic approach for the `ScoreCollection`, by making `SymmetricScoreCollection` a derived class of `ScoreCollection`  :

```
class SymetricScoreCollection: public ScoreCollection {
//define the member functions to access the values virtual
...
}; 

class SpecificAlgorithm : public SimilarityAlgorithm {
public:
  double run(node u, node v);

  // The specific algorithm is symmetric and thus uses a symmetric matrix to save memory
  ScoreCollection& runAll();
};
```

In fact it's an application of the [factory method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html), with the following roles:

- SimilarityAlgorithm is the factory,
- SpecificAlgorithm is the concrete factory
- ScoreCollection is the product
- SymetricScoreCollection is the concrete product

**Additional remark:**

Returning a reference to `ScoreCollection` from `runAll()` brings in some risks.  Suppose  `sa` is a specific algorithm.

In the following statement :

```
ScoreCollection sc = sa.runAll();
```

`sa.runAll()` returns a reference to a `SymetricScoreCollection`, but it would copy the referred object to sc, making it a ScoreCollection.  [Slicing](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/) occurs, and polymorphism will fail to work.

The following statement would however succeed:

```
ScoreCollection& rsc = sa.runAll();
```

because rsc is a reference and it would still refer to the original `SymetricScoreCollection` object returned by `sa.runAll()`, and everything would work as designed.

You see that it's very easy to have unnoticed mistakes when returning references.  I'd suggest to return a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you think about `runAll()` returning **rvalue references** to a member object? This would allow the caller to _steal_ the object from the algorithm. I didn't mention it but I don't want the algorithm to actually store the results from `runAll()`. In a perfect world I would like to return by value and also use covariance of return types. Is there a way to achieve something similar?

Comment: In this case you could define your collection to work with shared_ptr elements.